# How to detect reordering of ListView items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection;
Items in this list view can be reordered.

However, I have no idea how to detect when items have been reordered.
I can't find any relevant ListView event. And the ObservableCollection's CollectionChanged event is fired twice when an item is dragged ('Add' and 'Remove' events), so I don't think it is possible to tell if an item was actually moved in the UI or if I programmatically added a new item.

Is there any way to detect when items have been reordered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been thinking and I guess a workaround would be to disable the CollectionChanged event before adding an item programmatically and then enabling it again. That way, every time an item is added to the list I will _know_ it was caused by a reordering of the list items... I guess this would work, but it's waaay too far-fetched and violates a thousand software engineering principles...

Comment: I suppose you could detect reordering as both events triggered with the same object instance as the item. Why exactly do you need to know that reordering happened? How do you want to respond to that action? In most cases I can think of detecting the removal and readding of an item would have the same result in the end.

Comment: I need to detect this so I can update the DB with each item's new index, for persistence purposes. I also need to flag the item with `wasMoved = true` so I can sync with the backend server later. If I understood you correctly, you're suggesting I keep a (separate) collection of removed items, so when an item is added to my main ObservableCollection, I check if it's also in the collection of removed items. If it is, the item is being re-added and, therefore, moved in the UI. Right?

Comment: Yes, that was my basic idea. I know it's not a perfect approach, but considering what you've written, it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems there ARE events for reordering lists: DragItemsStarting and Drop. However, the Drop event currently only works with `ObservableVector<object>`

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/431cb3b4-0643-4a0e-8f1a-fc6e1e726ffb

Answer (score 0):

You should change your drag and drop. Check if your ItemsControl.DataContext is an ObservableCollection and if it is call .Move instead of .Remove and then .Add. This way, your underlying collection will get the correct event, and you can handle it simply.

You said you cannot implement dragging yourself, it is possible. Here is an example on a ListView that implements drag/drop between the same list and other lists. One option, is to start from here and modify it to call .Move instead. It also has the advantage of being able to draw the Adorners to make it look pretty.

[How to drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.UKJaGoex9vA)

I understand you may want to avoid having to implement this, I think your only other option is to expose a CollectionView for your Collection rather than rely on the default view that is created. I'm not sure if that will allow you to detect movement rather than add/remove though.

Comment: I'm not calling .Remove/.Add myself, the framework is, so I cannot simply change that. The ListView has `CanReorderItems`, `CanDragItems` and `AllowDrop` set to true, I did not implement the reordering logic myself.

Comment: @dcastro I added a link to an example that shows how to implement drag/drop yourself. It does some things you do not need like between different controls, and it doesn't call .Move (but it could)

Comment: That's WPF, I'm developing for WinRT... Either way, I found that there is a ListView event for detecting dropped items, except it's kinda broken.